# Should we use guard clauses in a method using auto validated properties of an object?

Tags: c#, encapsulation

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string A { get; }
    public string B { get; }
    public string C { get; }

    public MyClass(string a, string b, string c)
    {
        this.A = a ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(a));
        this.B = b ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(b));
        this.C = c ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(c));
    }
}
```

and some methods somewhere using an instance of it:

```
public void DoMagic(MyClass myClass)
{
    if(myClass == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myClass));

    // do stuff using myClass.A, myClass.B, myClass.C
}
```

At this point, we know for a fact that in the method body, neither myClass nor any of its properties can be null, and thus we can use them securely.

But this will break if at any point the spec for the class changes and all of a sudden one of its property becomes optional.

What is to be done in this case ? Should I rely on the properties being validated inside the class, or should I put guard clauses for A, B and C everywhere inide methods using them ? Wouldn't this bloat the code too much ?

Is there a general recommended strategy in this case ? Or several depending on some context variations ?

Comment: What is an example of a guard clause?

Comment: @paparazzo Something like `if(myClass.C == null) throw ...`

Comment: Stuff like this is why I wish CodeContracts was still being developed.

Comment: @Andy I couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would a property becoming optional break this approach? If it's optional, it's reasonable to assume it'll have a default value and thus still won't be `null`, eg:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public const string DefaultC = "";

    public string A { get; }
    public string B { get; }
    public string C { get; } = DefaultC;

    public MyClass(string a, string b, string c = DefaultC)
    {
        A = a ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(a));
        B = b ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(b));
        if (c != null) C = c;
        // or if you still want to throw on a null c, stay with,
        // C = c ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(c)); 
    }
}
```

So it can still be used securely.

Comment: Of course. I was wondering about the case where it would be made optional without any default value. But I guess it's up to us to prevent this from happening. I guess that's that simple :)

Comment: (1) `public string C { get; } = DefaultC;` (2) `string c = DefaultC` (3) `if (c != null) C = c;` This makes no sense. (3) tests for null, but (2) ensures that the value **can never be null** (it will be `DefaultC` if null was passed by the external caller). Therefore, (3) will always evaluate to true and will always set `C`. Which means that the default value in (1) and the if-check in (3) are both unnecessary.

Comment: @Flater, not so, unfortunately. [Please see here for what happens when `null` is passed and we remove that `if`](https://goo.gl/qDAt4E)

Comment: The compiler isn't required to abide by default values, which is partly why they should be avoided.